# How would I go about making a "Safe" .exe file with python?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I've made a program to generate a random order of names and have converted it into a .exe file through Pyinstaller.  It works fine but if I send it out, it will prompt the antivirus even though the file isn't harmful. I've tried looking for solutions in other places but they all require a form of payment, is there a free way I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge,

The quickest and safest way is to buy a windows certificate, this would make the file read completely safe even when sending it to another computer.

Unfortunately, the 'free' options are either super complicated/uncertain/long, etc, and would only work locally.

I suggest reading:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191003/how-to-prevent-my-executable-being-treated-from-av-like-bad-or-virus